# Assign value in a for loop and not reference

Tags: python, string, list, reference, variable-assignment

I have a list of strings and i'd like for each string in the list to store it in a dictionary and send it to another function. So far it looks like this:

```
list = ['75001', '75002', '75003']
params = {}
for elt in list:
    params['elt'] = elt
    ...
    foo(params)
```

But the problem is that i'm storing the reference to elt and not the value, so in my function calls i always have the last element of list:

```
params['elt'] = '75003'
```

How could i store only the value and not the reference ?

Comment: Can you explain what the keys of `params` are supposed to be? Naturally, if you assign a lot of things to `params['elt']`, then the last one will take precedence.

Comment: the keys of params will contain informations about a real-estate search. So it will be things like zip code, town, price range, etc..
Here the list contains zip codes actually.

Comment: So to what real-estate search information does the key `'elt'` correspond -- zip code? In that case you'd want something like `params['zip code'] = elt`. Also you shouldn't use `list` as the name of a variable because it's already the name of a built-in Python type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all functions get the same dictionary. Try this instead:

```
list = ['75001', '75002', '75003']
for elt in list:
    params = {}
    params['elt'] = elt
    ...
    foo(params)
```

Now each call to `foo()` gets a new container and they can't see each other anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = ['75001', '75002', '75003']
params = {}
for elt in list:
    params[elt] = elt
    ...
    foo(params)
```

Just remove the quotes around `elt` in `params['elt']`. What you're currently doing is repeatedly changing the value for the key `'elt'`.

If you want a new dictionary each time however you can do this:

```
list = ['75001', '75002', '75003']
for elt in list:
    foo({'elt': elt})
```

Comment: I see what you are saying there (i think), but i need my key to be named 'elt'.
In fact, at each loop i'm sending a request containing the params dictionary.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do. Store multiple values in the same key?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dict that doesn't change after you pass it to foo, you should make a copy of that dict:

```
params = {}
for elt in list:
    params['elt'] = elt
    ...
    foo(params.copy())
```

Now, further changes to `params` later in the loop won't affect the copy of `params` that you sent to `foo`.

This differs from Aaron Digulla's answer in that `params` can still be initially created outside the loop. This can be useful if params was declared far away up in the code, and you don't want to move it into the loop; or if the initial instantiation was expensive and you don't want to do it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
zip_codes = ['75001', '75002', '75003']
for zip_code in zip_codes:
    params = {}
    params['zip code'] = zip_code
    ...
    foo(params)
```

This creates a new empty dictionary each time through the loop and adds values from the list to it before calling `foo()` although you don't really need that unless you're sure you assign to the same keys each time through the loop. An alternative would be to move it back out of the loop and call `params.clear()` at the top of the loop. Of course other keys and corresponding pieces of search information could be added before calling `foo()` as necessary.